# Transitive and Inverse properties in Protege

Tags: ontology, protege

I have modeled the following object properties in my Ontology:

```
Harbor locatedIn some City
City locatedIn some Country
```

I want the inferential engine to infer that a

```
Harbor locatedIn some Country
```

Moreover, I want him to infer that a

```
City hasHarbor(another object property) some Harbor
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** to infer that: `Harbor subClassOf locatedIn some Country` 
You should define `locatedIn` as `Transitive` (you can use protege GUI)

**Second:** The reasoner won't create `hasHarbor` property on its own. It should be defined first, and you can assert it as `inverseOf` `locatedIn` (you can use protege GUI).